# Is there a way to make one function stop all the other functions?

Tags: javascript, execute

I want only one of these functions to run at a time. Is there a way to stop executing a function while continuing another?

For example, If function "do_move_right()" is currently executing, I want to be able to press a button that makes the function stop executing and start executing function "do_move_left()".

CODE:

```
function do_move_right() {
    sheepr = document.getElementById('sb');
    mover = sheepr.style.left;
    mover = parseInt(mover.substring(0,mover.length-2));


    mover += 10;
    sheepr.style.left = (mover)+'px';


    if (mover < 940) {

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        do_move_right('sb');
      }, 250);
    }
}

function do_move_left() {
    sheepl = document.getElementById('sb');
    movel = sheepl.style.left;
    movel = parseInt(movel.substring(0,movel.length-2));


    movel -= 10;
    sheepl.style.left = (movel)+'px';


    if (movel < 940) {

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        do_move_left('sb');
      }, 250);
    }
}

function do_move_up() {
    sheepu = document.getElementById('sb');
    moveu = sheepu.style.top;
    moveu = parseInt(moveu.substring(0,moveu.length-2));


    moveu -= 10;
    sheepu.style.top = (moveu)+'px';


    if (moveu < 940) {

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        do_move_up('sb');
      }, 250);
    }
}

function do_move_down() {
    sheepd = document.getElementById('sb');
    moved = sheepd.style.top;
    moved = parseInt(moved.substring(0,moved.length-2));


    moved += 10;
    sheepd.style.top = (moved)+'px';


    if (moved < 940) {

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        do_move_down('sb');
      }, 250);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript can not be running two functions at the same time. Once a function is entered, it will continue through it until it returns. There is no way to interrupt it unless the function itself returns early (like if you used a if statement to check a exit early condition).

So something you might be looking for is a variable that you can set on the fly that the functions check to see if they are allowed to do their thing. Something like:

```
var canMoveLeft = true;
```

Just check for that var in your do_move_left() function before you do anything and return early if the test fails.

Comment: Actually in your case, you may want to wrap your inner function content with the if statement so that whether the test passes or fails, you can do the setTimeout right after the closing brace of the if statement.